# Same image, two sizes

Tags: css, html, image

I was thinking what is the "best pratice":

In a HTML page, I have one icon that is small in menu and big in the inline text. Visually is the same image, but it is loaded as two different images. I am calling using each as a base64 source, but this question also applies to external img.

So is it better to:

1. Load 2 different images, with 2 requests to server and almost 2x download size (or inline base64 size)
2. Load only bigger image, and client-side resize it to a small size

Comment: You may also look at SVG and load your icon only once for all (svg for scallable graphist vector ;) )

Comment: Unfortunately your question is very opinion based. My advice is to use the method that requires the least development time, since the end result would look identical visually. Premature optimization and all that

Comment: The answer depends a lot on context and not only your context but also the various server details and environments you're comfortable with editing to reach or improve that context.... as Socki states in his answer. For instance, for desktop browser only you might as well just load the big image and scale it down, that's fine, but for mobile browsing you should only load the big one if the visitor wants to view the big one.....

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's better to only reference the larger image and use it downscaled for the second instance - when you load it first, it's in the cache, there is no additional server request and no additional loading time. The scaling can't take as much time or processing power and whatever as laoding a second image. Also `srcset` will load two different images in this case, so boils down to the same scenario as without srcset.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of boils down to your server, caching ability, load time, and expected clientelle (mobile heavy or desktop heavy).

I prefer to load larger images even on smaller sizes so they look nicer on retina devices.  This was my practice over the last few years.  However, something I recommend you research is [img srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/).

It's the next thing, and has [pretty good (non-IE) support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this. Let's say that the image is loaded on the page as such:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

This has made a call already to the backend, and you wanted to make it appear elsewhere in a block of text without making the call again to the server. There is no convenient way to load a smaller version of the picture a second time on a seperate point on the page. This is why most places will have multiple pictures saved of different dimensions.

If it is a particularly large image, you might try using a lower resolution image on the load, or loading it with SVG.